# Lack of memory property of probability distributions

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-theory, probability-distributions

According to wikipedia lack of memory property applies to geometric and exponential distributions. I was trying to apply it to binomial distribution. Am I modelling my question correctly?

So imagine a fair coin toss and X the random variable for number of heads. Assume number of trials to be 7.

Question:  what is the probability that in seven tosses of a fair coin first 2 are tails and in remaining 5 tosses you get three heads?

So should the answer be:
0.5 x 0.5 x (5c3 x 0.5^3 x 0.5^2)

And how is it different from the following question:
Tom tosses a coin twice and gets 2 tails. What is the probability that he will get three heads in remaining 5 tosses?

If the lack of memory property came into picture second time then is it correct to say that lack of memory property applies to binomial distribution too.

Comment: These are two different notions of "lack-of-memory". One applies to the distribution of a single random variable, the other to a sequence of independent random variables.

Answer (score 1):

to the second question: The first two tosses must not be considered because the results already confirmed.

greetings,

calculus